# Using Azure VM VHD for local VM installation

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, hypervisor

I have a VM running in Azure.  Is it possible to download the VHD from blob storage and use it to create/launch a VM on my local machine using hypervisor?

If this is possible, do you believe Windows 2012 server licensing could be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from purely technical perspective it should work locally once VHD is downloaded. If VHD fails to mount locally, make a local copy of a downloaded VHD file and then mount that resulting copy.

Comment: it's actually documented here http://blogs.technet.com/b/cbernier/archive/2014/01/27/move-vm-s-between-hyper-v-and-windows-azure.aspx, but what happens if i don't run sysprep?

Comment: as long as VM config is compatible with on-prem network (no machine name clashes, etc), should work without sysprep

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your licensing question, according to this page: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/

> *Can I move Windows Server 2012 licenses and images between Hyper-V and Azure?* Windows Server licenses are not eligible for License
>   Mobility through Software Assurance. The license to run Windows Server
>   in the Azure environment is included in the per-minute cost of your
>   Windows Virtual Machine. Licenses for use of Windows Server
>   on-premises (whether in a VHD or otherwise) must be obtained
>   separately through volume licensing.

In other words, the Windows license cost is included in the Azure per-minute cost you pay.  If you download the VHD and use it in house, you must have a license.